# Versioned Google App Engine site can’t be reached

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I have a static website for which I would like to deploy preview for each git commit. I am using Google App Engine for this.

I am able to succesfully deploy this. The version shows up in the versions section in the Google Cloud console, which also renders a nice link. However, when I click the link, the site can’t be reached.

Let’s say the project id is `bar`, the service id is `foo`, and are two versions, 1 and 2, where 1 is promoted. (This isn’t real data)

https://foo-dot-bar.appspot.com is reachable in this case, but
https://1-dot-foo-dot-bar.appspot.com and https://2-dot-foo-dot-bar.appspot.com are not.

Do I need to configure anything for this to work? Is it a Google Cloud bug?

Comment: This *should* work, provided, of course, that the respective services aren't somehow sensitive to such changes in the hostname portion of the URLs (not impossible). Do you use a dispatch file?

Comment: Besides the dispatch file, what is the status of the versions? Are they running?

Comment: We do use a dispatch file. I’ll need to discuss this with a coworker as soon as he gets back from vacation. For now I’ll let this sit for a while. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction (I think)! And yes, all versions are serving.

Comment: Also, there should be any error logs in your Console, so if you comeback, please post them here (sanitising any possible private information, of course).